# SSIS Bulk insert error when using SQL authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bulkinsert, ssis-2012

An SSIS bulk insert error is received when using SQL authentication, while I can insert data when I use windows authentication.

> [Bulk Insert Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\BCP\extract_remove_ref.bcp" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).".

Answer (score 4):

When doing a `BULK INSERT` with SQL Server authentication the credentials of the account used by the SQL Server service are used as specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  To resolve this, grant access to the folders/files that are being used in the `BULK INSERT` operation to the account that the SQL Server service runs under.  This can be done through Windows by right-clicking on the folder/files and going to **Properties** > **Security** > **Edit** > **Add** and type in the account name.  If you're unable to find it, make sure the right account type is selected in the **Object Types** window and choose the proper location from the **Locations** window.  If you're having trouble finding the account, type use the **Check Names** option.

---

## Update 1 - Official documentation

Referring to the following official documentation:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

**To Grant File System Permission to the Per-service SID**

> 1. Using Windows Explorer, navigate to the file system location where the database files are stored. Right-click the file system folder, and then click Properties.
> 2. On the Security tab, click Edit, and then Add.
> 3. In the Select Users, Computer, Service Account, or Groups dialog box, click Locations, at the top of the location list, select your computer name, and then click OK.
> 4. In the Enter the object names to select box, type the name of the per-service SID name listed in the Books Online topic Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions. (For the Database Engine per service SID name, use NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER for a default instance, or NT SERVICE\MSSQL$InstanceName for a named instance.)
> 5. Click Check Names to validate the entry. (If the validation fails, it might advise you that the name was not found. When you click OK, a Multiple Names Found dialog box appears. Now select the per-service SID name, either MSSQLSERVER or NT SERVICE\MSSQL$InstanceName, and then click OK. Click OK again to return to the Permissions dialog box.)
> 6. In the Group or user names box, select the per-service SID name, and then in the Permissions for  box, select the Allow check box for Full control.
> 7. Click Apply, and then click OK twice to exit.

**Additional Information**

- [Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened](https://sqlbak.com/blog/cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-could-not-be-opened-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied/)

Comment: I deleted my answer since it is better to combine it with yours. +1

Comment: Adding official references is always recommended +1

Comment: Yes I agree combining the answers makes sense, thanks @Hadi.